# Structure of a correctly implemented JTable with TableModel and Listeners?

Tags: java, architecture, sql

I am pretty new to Java and its JTables and this is where I am struggling at the moment.

I need to create a GUI which shows me results of a sql query like `SELECT * FROM tblPeople WHERE name='Doe'`. My idea was to create a a JFrame which displays a JTable with all found records.

Besides this, I  need to also implement some code to handle when a user is double clicking a record or selecting it by using his arrow keys (additional feature: pressing `12`(e.g.) should select the 12th record).

What is the best way to structure my program (what classes do I need and especially where do I store my logic)? I came up with structuring it the following way:

- **Main.java** ("view")
- **SQLConnection.java**
- **PeopleTableModel.java** (only stores and returns data given by the passed ResultSet, "model" inherits from DefaultTableModel)
- **PeopleTable.java** (stores basically all my logic including KeyListener and MouseListener, "controller", inherits from JTable)

Are there better ways to achieve my goals? If so, what are they?

Comment: Thank you @Martijn Pieters for you grammar & spell checks! You know, my bad English is very! ;) ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use model-view-controller design pattern. In the class view you will have the GUI components. In the class model you will have the logic of your program. In the controller you choose what data to pass from model to view and vice versa.

I also recommend you to use a class for each table from DB, like in hibernate. And  you will have a class DBAccess, where you access the DB and make queries. Be aware that in Java it is recommended that a class to have a single responsibility. That will make your program more easy to test.